# how to give error message to placeholder by using jquery bassistance plugin

Tags: php, jquery, css

is this possible to give error message inside text box, i.e placeholder place if possible give me an idea.how to give error placement to get error message in inside text field.

how many ways we can make error placement by using bassistance plugin

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can make it, you don't even have to use jquery libraries and such. You can just do it with javascript and css.

I made you an example in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yQpXj/3/

if the text in the inputfield isn't longer then 5 characters, it puts "too short" as placeholder

it uses `document.getElementById("inputbox").placeholder="too short";` to change placeholder and `document.getElementById("inputbox").setAttribute("class", "red");` to give it a class and to make the placeholder red with css (I did it for a variety of browsers).

When you are done with your validation, you can use `document.forms["myForm"].submit();` to submit the form.

Hope it helped! :)